# Camera provides striped image - what's wrong?

Tags: python, raspicam

I've been using the raspi cam for some time now.
I was using it inside a machine, to take photos from what's going on there.
As far as I can tell, the cables are all attached as they should be -
but all of a sudden, the images look like this.

Can anybody help? What's going on here?

[image]

In the preview window, the photo looks normal.
After a restart, the output is completely black instead.

This is my test code which makes the same output as the production code.
First, I measure the lighting and fix the camera setting. Then I take a series of photos while the machine works.

I take the photo in the original cam's format (rgb), crop it with numpy slicing and save it afterwards.
That had been the fastest image taking process I was able to come up with.

Around 12 000 photos later, the camera does this. Why? What can I do about it?

```
from time import sleep
from picamera import PiCamera
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

CROPBOX = (317, 464, 317+370, 464+251) #x0,y0,x1,y1
RESOLUTION = (1024, 768)

cam = PiCamera(camera_num=0, 
      resolution=RESOLUTION, 
      framerate=40, 
      sensor_mode=0, 
      clock_mode='reset', 
      framerate_range=None)

cam.meter_mode = 'average'
#cam.zoom = 0.3, 0.3, 0.65, 0.65
cam.iso = 50
sleep(0.5)
cam.shutter_speed = cam.exposure_speed
cam.exposure_mode = 'off'
sleep(0.5)

# fix white bracket
gains = cam.awb_gains
cam.awb_mode = 'off'
cam.awb_gains = gains

x0, y0, x1, y1 = CROPBOX
output = np.empty((RESOLUTION[0], RESOLUTION[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cam.capture(output, "rgb")
Image.fromarray(output[y0:y1,x0:x1,:]).save("test_image.png")
cam.close()
```

Comment: If this suddenly happens after 12000 successful pictures, without any code change, I would assume that something broke. Try getting a new camera.

Comment: Thanks PMF! I am constantly editing my code. This edit, I totally forgot between the last run and this one. It was not yet tested, last time I had no time left. I found the error (see below).

Comment: That's what git (or any other versioning software) is for, actually ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error.

I define `RESOLUTION` here and use it correctly

```
RESOLUTION = (1024, 768)
cam = PiCamera(camera_num=0, 
    resolution=RESOLUTION, 
    framerate=40, 
    sensor_mode=0, 
    clock_mode='reset', 
    framerate_range=None)
```

But then in the capture area I use it in the same order, and there it is wrong:

```
output = np.empty((RESOLUTION[0], RESOLUTION[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Because that's the **old numpy trap** - images have it the other way round than numpy. I should have used this instead:

```
output = np.empty((RESOLUTION[1], RESOLUTION[0], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Because, effectively, `numpy` slicing uses what is y in images as first argument, and what is x in images as second argument. That's the way `numpy` is organized.